# Placing column headings over the column without a border?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to place the column headings over the columns without the borders around them. Ideally the table should look like the picture I include in this post, but it's smushed and I'm not really sure why because I don't do tables often. Any idea what's gone wrong? Any help is appreciated. [image: Picture of the table here]

```css
/* 
   CSS for Lounge Project 
   Filename: styles.css
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
*/

/*Drink font colors*/
h2.green {
 color: green;
}

h2.blue {
 color: blue;
}

h2.purple {
 color: purple;
}

h2.red {
 color: red;
}

h2.yellow {
 color: gold;
}

/*center and border image*/
img.smlounge {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 3px solid;
 border-color: red;
}

/*Table styles*/
td, th {
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 width: 60%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Head First Lounge Elixirs</title>

   <!-- 
   Elixir page for Lounge Project 
   Filename: elixir.html
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
   -->

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../lounge.css" />
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <h1>Our Elixirs</h1>

    <h2 class="green">Green Tea Cooler</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="../images/green.jpg" alt="Green Tea Cooler"/>
      Chock full of vitamins and minerals, this elixir
      combines the healthful benefits of green tea with
      a twist of chamomile blossoms and ginger root.
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h2 class="blue">Raspberry Ice Concentration</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="../images/lightblue.jpg" alt="Rasberry Ice Concentration"/>
      Combining raspberry juice with lemon grass,
      citrus peel and rosehips, this icy drink
      will make your mind feel clear and crisp.
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h2 class="purple">Blueberry Bliss Elixir</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="../images/blue.jpg" alt="Blueberry Bliss Elixir"/>
      Blueberries and cherry essence mixed into a base
      of elderflower herb tea will put you in a relaxed
      state of bliss in no time.
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h2 class="red">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="../images/red.jpg" alt="Cranberry Antioxidant Blast"/>
      Wake up to the flavors of cranberry and hibiscus
      in this vitamin C rich elixir.
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h2 class="yellow"><a name="Yellow">Lemon Breeze</a></h2>
    <p><img src="../images/yellow.gif" alt="Lemon Breeze Drink"/>
      The ultimate healthy drink, this elixir combines
      herbal botanicals, minerals, and vitamins with
      a twist of lemon into a smooth citrus wonder
      that will keep your immune system going all
      day and all night.
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6">Our Drink Prices</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Drink</th>
                <th colspan="2">Size</th>
                <th colspan="2">Price</th>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Green Tea Cooler</td>
                <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
                <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
                <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Raspberry Ice Concentration</td>
                <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
                <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
                <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</td>
                <td colspan="2">20 oz.</td>
                <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Lemon Breeze</td>
                <td>Iced</td>
                <td>16 oz.</td>
                <td>$3.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Frozen</td>
                <td>20 oz.</td>
                <td>$4.75</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <p><a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a></p>
    
    <footer>
      &#169;2016, Head First Online Lounge<br />
      All trademarks and registered trademarks appearing on this site are 
      the property of their respective owners.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **In what way is it "smushed"?** As developers, we see a lot of broken code, much of which may be described with either the word "smushed" or with much more colourful terms.

Comment: Well if you look at the table that's in the code you can see the entire right hand side of the table under the "price" heading is much smaller than the other two columns. That's what I'm referring to when I say smushed, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the CSS [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) property. Remove the `width: 60%;` declaration from `td, th` and add:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

I also added a `.drink-name` selector to ease the job of centering certain table cells while left-aligning others. Feel free to change the `padding` I added to each cell as you see fit.

To make the columns equal-width, you should add:

```
td[colspan="2"] {
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```css
/* 
   CSS for Lounge Project 
   Filename: styles.css
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
*/


/*Drink font colors*/

h2.green {
  color: green;
}

h2.blue {
  color: blue;
}

h2.purple {
  color: purple;
}

h2.red {
  color: red;
}

h2.yellow {
  color: gold;
}


/*center and border image*/

img.smlounge {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: red;
}


/*Table styles*/

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1em ;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td[colspan="2"] {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.drink-name {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Head First Lounge Elixirs</title>

  <!-- 
   Elixir page for Lounge Project 
   Filename: elixir.html
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
   -->

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../lounge.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Elixirs</h1>

  <h2 class="green">Green Tea Cooler</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/green.jpg" alt="Green Tea Cooler" /> Chock full of vitamins and minerals, this elixir combines the healthful benefits of green tea with a twist of chamomile blossoms and ginger root.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="blue">Raspberry Ice Concentration</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/lightblue.jpg" alt="Rasberry Ice Concentration" /> Combining raspberry juice with lemon grass, citrus peel and rosehips, this icy drink will make your mind feel clear and crisp.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="purple">Blueberry Bliss Elixir</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/blue.jpg" alt="Blueberry Bliss Elixir" /> Blueberries and cherry essence mixed into a base of elderflower herb tea will put you in a relaxed state of bliss in no time.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="red">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/red.jpg" alt="Cranberry Antioxidant Blast" /> Wake up to the flavors of cranberry and hibiscus in this vitamin C rich elixir.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="yellow"><a name="Yellow">Lemon Breeze</a></h2>
  <p><img src="../images/yellow.gif" alt="Lemon Breeze Drink" /> The ultimate healthy drink, this elixir combines herbal botanicals, minerals, and vitamins with a twist of lemon into a smooth citrus wonder that will keep your immune system going all day
    and all night.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6">Our Drink Prices</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="border-right:0">Drink</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="border-left:0;border-right:0">Size</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="border-left:0">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Green Tea Cooler</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Raspberry Ice Concentration</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="drink-name">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</td>
        <td colspan="2">20 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Lemon Breeze</td>
        <td>Iced</td>
        <td>16 oz.</td>
        <td>$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Frozen</td>
        <td>20 oz.</td>
        <td>$4.75</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p><a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a></p>

  <footer>
    &#169;2016, Head First Online Lounge<br /> All trademarks and registered trademarks appearing on this site are the property of their respective owners.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That fixes the same column problem, but do you know how to make the columns all fit to the same size? Two of them look the same size while the third is much smaller and doesn't look like the picture at all.

Comment: Sure, let me update my example. Give me a moment and I'll let you know when I finish.

Comment: @SkryBlackfall Should be fixed now. Let me know what you think and if you have any questions :)

Comment: Yeah I just have one. How did you get so good at this? That would have taken me forever to figure that out.

Comment: Mostly self-taught. I read lots of documentation, pored over blogs like [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com), and built a few websites for practice. With time, you will get there too! :)

Comment: Thanks so much mate. I'll look into that blog. One last question though is how do I get the "price, drink and size" headings to be all in one box but still over their respective columns?

Comment: I am on mobile right now, so I can't see the rendered example but I believe I fixed the problem. Let me know :)

Comment: Yep looks like that fixed it. Any idea how to do that double border thing that's happening in the last couple boxes? Looks kinda weird, but I think I'm supposed to do that as well. It also says the table should be centered on the page and span 60% of the width of the page with each of the main three columns comprising 20%.

Comment: I cannot edit at the moment, sorry, but give me a few hours and I can get back to you. If you want to take a crack at it yourself between now and then the CSS requires `border-style: double`

Comment: I figured out what it is. It's a nested table within a table. I think to do it I need to recode the last two <td>'s in the last row and in each of them I'll have a new table element. The first one will be two rows with two columns each and the second will be two rows with one column. Now I just have to figure out how to put that as code.

Comment: Sounds like you have a handle on it. Just mimic the structure of your original `table` and see where it leads. If you find yourself stuck down the road feel free to edit your question with the new code and I can provide some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, close your thead and tbody tags properly and then add this code in your css.  here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ohtduqso/

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

th {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't slept in awhile so I didn't see the open tags I guess. The third column is still too small though. Do you know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/v86x4ehh/1/

just add these classes to your css

```
table tr:nth-child(2){
  border:none;
  }
table{

  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```